# How to change scientific outcome in "normal" number?

Tags: pascal, normalize

When I was making my first exercises in PASCAL I came across a very large (scientific) outcome. I asked my coach from course how to fix this. He didn't know the answer.

I searched on Google how to convert this, but no luck finding the right answer.
So I thought lets ask here.

The outcome is "2.150000000E+02".
Anyone knows how to convert this into normal number like 2150 (or something like that)

PS: The code as requested:

```
  // 
program LOON;



var uren,overuren,bruto: integer;

begin
// 
writeln('Geef uren, uurloon en overuren in');
// 
readln(UREN,OVERUREN,BRUTO);
// 
writeln('Het effectieve loon bedraagt' ,(UREN+OVERUREN*1.5)*BRUTO);
// 
writeln();
// 
writeln('Druk op <ENTER> om het programma te verlaten');
// 
readln();
writeln();
writeln('Druk op <ENTER> om het programma te verlaten');
readln():;
end.
```

Comment: What does "outcome" mean? You need to be specific about what you're asking. Numbers don't have "outcomes"; they have values. What kind of "number" are you using? What is a "normal number"?

Comment: @KenWhite  As I said in other post, im total beginner... So forgive me if I make mistakes :)
I used integer variabele, and the outcome or value at the end of the program is 2.150000000E+02, where it should be 2150. Is there a way to  get this normal outcome?

Comment: It is a scientific notation. E+02 is power of 10 raised to 2, which is 100. That means 2.15*100 which is 215. Most pascal compilers have a StrToFloat function that accepts a string with scientific notation.

Comment: @LURD I want to get rid of the scientific notation and have it displayed in "normal human" notation

Comment: Then you have to show how you get this string in the first place. There are format functions that can let you specify the output format.

Comment: If the line is from your last question, `writeln('Het effectieve loon bedraagt' ;(UREN+OVERUREN*1.5)*BRUTO);`, then write it like this:`writeln('Het effectieve loon bedraagt' ;(UREN+OVERUREN*1.5)*BRUTO:0:2);`.

Comment: OK  I will edit the question and put my code in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using FreePascal, you can use [FormatFloat](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/formatfloat.html) function: `FormatFloat('0.00', Val);`. If you are using old TP use formatting with Write/WriteLn like this: `WriteLn(Val:0:2);`.

Comment: and where do I put it in my code, tried a few things but got errors:
LOON.pas(5,17) Error: Type identifier expected
LOON.pas(8,1) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "VAR" found
I probably misplaced it somewhere, or dont know how or what...

Comment: try this: `writeln('Het effectieve loon bedraagt' ,(UREN+OVERUREN*1.5)*BRUTO:0:2);`

Comment: that did the trick :)

TYVM, now im going to tell this to my coach...
He didnt know how to fix this LOL

Comment: You can play with formating by altering two numbers after **:**. First number is used for alignment, second for length of decimal part. You can find more information here: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Formatting_output

Comment: Will definately look into the wiki!

Comment: Beware that these functions do not work [precisely](http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=23196) and in 2.6 sometimes even return a completely wrong result (1 instead 1e16)